# Google sheets array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
Column A     Column B    Column C
yes          apple       apple
no           banana      peach
no           pear
yes          peach
```

(in google sheets)

How to I make a simple array that will output as shown above?

I currently have:

```
    =if(A1="yes,b1,"")
    =if(A2="yes,b2,"")
    =if(A3="yes,b3,"")
    =if(A4="yes,b4,"")
```

But the output is:

```
Column A     Column B    Column C
    yes          apple       apple
    no           banana       
    no           pear
    yes          peach       peach
```

SOLVED!

```
=FILTER(B1:B4,A1:A4="yes")
```

Comment: look for csv files... those look pretty much like that ;)

Comment: and for sure, you need a programming language....

Comment: You can use Query or Filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to filter C column showing only rows where B column contains "Yes"

```
=filter(C2:C,B2:B="Yes")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(A2 = "yes",B2,"")
```

[image]